# Xtics label are not shown in the whole hight

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, axis-labels

How to solve this problem with xticks labels please?

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

doesn't help.

[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import re

x = ('5L8 9O7 4H 7F')
print(type(x))
xaxes = x.split()
y = [4.7, 5.7, 4, 6.4]
print(xaxes)
print(y)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [11,15]

splitted_xaxes = [re.search('^([0-9]*)([^0-9]*)([0-9]*)$', label).groups() for label in xaxes ]
xaxes = [r'${}^{'+splitted[0]+r'}_{}'+splitted[1]+r'^{'+splitted[2] + '}_{}$' for splitted in splitted_xaxes]

plt.scatter(xaxes,y)

plt.xlabel(r'$\it{L}$', fontsize=20, labelpad=30) #labelpad - vzdálenost od osy
plt.ylabel(r'$\it{LK}$ (eV)', fontsize=20)
plt.title('Img', fontsize=28, fontweight='bold')
plt.yticks(fontsize=18)
plt.xticks(fontsize=18)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('img.png', dpi=199) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: One cannot help you unless you show your code. Since you are new to this site, please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I editted the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `_{}` in your string. I.e.

```
'${}^{8}S_{}$'
```

[image]

but

```
'${}^{8}S$'
```

[image]

---

The underlying problem is [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15313).